# How to read name of the files in a folder using React

Tags: reactjs, file

We have a requirement to add a download button, when the user clicks on it, a user should be able to download the PDF file which was dynamically added within a react project folder.

We have a static path to the PDF folder but cannot read the file's name. How to read the file name in React so that the user can download the PDF?

The folder structure is,

```
src
 pdf/
   x.pdf
 app.tsx
```

within `app.tsx`, we have a HTML code like this,

```
let pdfFile = './pdf/<Need to get a name of the file here which can be anything>';
<button><a href={pdfFile}> Download </a> <button>
```

Comment: Please share the code you are working with, so we can get a deeper understanding of the problem.

Comment: @Severin added a sample snippet above for a better understanding.

Comment: This is a JavaScript question, not a React question, and reading directory contents from the browser is not usually allowed, for security reasons.

Comment: How did you "dynamically" add the pdf file to the folder? If you are fetching the pdf from somewhere you should have the  pdf file name.